# How to delete image in database also in source folder

Tags: php, ajax, image

Can any one help me how to delete the image inside the folder?
this my code for deleting the image inside the database and its working

```
<?php
require('connection/dbconn.php');
    if(ISSET($_POST['id'])){

        foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id){
            $dbconn->query("delete from `uploading` where `id` = '$id'");
    }    
}
?>
```

Comment: With what exact part are you struggling?

Comment: i don't know the code of deleting the image file in the folder.

Answer (score 2):

For deleting file with PHP, you have to use [`unlink` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

But you have to also provide a filepath, which is in your case should consists from upload directory path and fileID (which is `$_POST['id']`?)

```
/**
 * Do user permissions check for this operation before going further
 */
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $fileId) {
    $filePath = "/path/to/upload/dir/$fileId";
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        unlink($filePath);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to make security and data consistency checks. For example, that the user, that sent this request for deleting has enough rights for it.

Comment: for clarification I forgot to include, I used ajax for this and delete using checkbox
the name of the checkbox is "id[]" as you can see " foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id)"

Comment: oh, I see. So instead of $_POST['id'] here you should use $id which is single element of your $_POST['id'] array.

Comment: is this correct?  
`foreach ($_POST['id'] as $fileId){
   $dbconn->query("delete from `uploading` where `id` = '$fileId'");
            $filePath = "artifactimage/$fileId";
            if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            unlink($filePath);

 } `

Answer (score 0):

To delete the image from server, you will have to pass the`imageName` variable to your PHP script, and then you can delete the file using built-in function `unlink()`:

```
$path = //your path to the upload images

unlink( $path . $imageName);
unlink( $path . 'Thumbnails/' . $imageName); //if also have thumbnail
```

You are interacting with your server file system, you'll want to be sure and sanitize the variables (prevent someone from using ../../../ to get to unwanted parts of your file system).

```
$imageName= str_replace( array( '..', '/', '\\', ':' ), '', $imageName);
```

You should sanitize the variables to make sure you escape .. characters in the filename otherwise you could something like "../../../public/index.php

**Update:**

You would have to store the name of an image in the database and create a hidden field in your delete form. While deleting, get the image name as `$image = $_POST['image'];` and then follow the `unlink` process.

Comment: for clarification I forgot to include, I used ajax for this and delete using checkbox
the name of the checkbox is "id[]" as you can see " foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id)"

Comment: Do you understand why you are using `foreach`? For instance, `foreach` is used to process data in an array. So, if you want to delete only one entry, then there is no use of `foreach`. Kindly describe the usage of your code to let me help you effectively.

Comment: I used checkbox so that i can delete multiple image and I used AJAX. The problems is the image in the folder cant delete.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select image name from db or send image name with **id**
2. Use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) function to delete file image

```
unlink('/path-to-upload-dir/' . $_POST['imagename']);
```

Comment: so it will look like this?
<?php
require('connection/dbconn.php');
    if(ISSET($_POST['id'])){
        
  foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id){
   $dbconn->query("delete from `uploading` where `id` = '$id'");
            unlink('aritactimage/' . $_POST['artifact_name']);
 }    
}
?>